# Random forest: OOB for k-fold cross-validation?

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation, r-caret

I am rather new to machine learning and I am currently trying to implement a random forest classification using the caret and randomForest packages in R. I am using the trainControl function with repeated cross-validation. Maybe it is a stupid question but as far as I understand random forest usually uses bagging to split the training data into different subsets with replacement using 1/3 as a validation set based on which the OOB is calculated on. But what happens if you specify that you want to use k-fold cross-validation? From the caret documentation, I assumed that it uses only cross-validation for the resampling, But if it only used cross-validation, why do you still get an OOB error? Or is bagging still used for the creation of the model and cross-validation for the performance evaluation?

```
TrainingControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 3, savePredictions = TRUE, classProbs = TRUE, search = "grid")

train(x ~ ., data = training_set,
           method = "rf",
           metric = "Accuracy",            
           trControl = TrainingControl,
           ntree = 1000,  
           importance = TRUE              
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to address your questions:

> random forest usually uses bagging to split the training data into
> different subsets with replacement using 1/3 as a validation set based
> on which the OOB is calculated on

Yes, caret is using `randomForest()` from the package `randomForest`, and more specifically, it bootstraps on the training data, generate multiple decision tress which are bagged, to reduce overfitting, from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest):

> This bootstrapping procedure leads to better model performance because
> it decreases the variance of the model, without increasing the bias.
> This means that while the predictions of a single tree are highly
> sensitive to noise in its training set, the average of many trees is
> not, as long as the trees are not correlated.

So if you call k-fold cross-validation from caret, it simply runs `randomForest()` on different training sets, therefore the answer to this:

> But what happens if you specify that you want to use k-fold
> cross-validation? From the caret documentation, I assumed that it uses
> only cross-validation for the resampling, But if it only used
> cross-validation, why do you still get an OOB error?

Would be the sampling and bagging is performed because it is part of `randomforest`. `caret` simply repeats this on different training set and estimates the error on their respective test set. The OOB error generated from `randomForest()` stays regardless. The difference is that you have a truly "unseen" data that can be used to evaluate your model.